# "Cannot specify decimal(5,2) data type (parameter 4) as a substitution parameter" error on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 I get the following error:

> Cannot specify decimal(5,2) data type (parameter 4) as a substitution
>   parameter.

Just had a look at the trigger on the table and it looks like the issue has to do with this `if`

```
if @SumField7 <> 100
    begin
        rollback tran
        raiserror ('...%d...', 16, 1, @SumField7)
    end
```

Comment: column names are atrocious...

Comment: Works without any problem on SQL Server 2008 R2 ...

Comment: As far as I can see from looking at `sys.messages` this looks like you are using `RAISERROR` somewhere. Perhaps in a trigger? Can you show us the code for that?

Comment: What client are you using to run the query?  Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: It is running in vb.net code. Though once it gave the error I tried it in Sql Server Management Studio. Same error given.

Comment: I can't make it fail. In what context are you running the query? SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm just about to find out if there is a trigger on the table. I unfortunately don't have access to the 2008 server. Once I have that info I'll share it.

Comment: @Zugwalt - Regarding your now deleted answer [there is a request for this type of `option strict` functionality here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260762)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is easy to reproduce

```
declare @SumField7 decimal(5,2) = 123.45

raiserror ('...%d...', 16, 1, @SumField7)
```

You are specifying `%d` as the Type specification which [represents signed integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) but passing it a `decimal`. Maybe this was never type checked in SQL Server 2000.

It looks like there is no syntax for `decimal` place holders and you would need to pass a string instead as below.

```
declare @SumField7 decimal(5,2) = 123.45
declare @SumField7String varchar(7) = @SumField7

raiserror ('...%s...', 16, 1, @SumField7String)
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is usually caused by a [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) and mismatch of parameters vs placeholder.

Do you have a trigger with RAISERROR? It isn't the INSERT...

Comment: I'm just about to find out if there is a trigger on the table. I unfortunately don't have access to the 2008 server. Once I have that info I'll share it.

Comment: Updated question with what I think the issue is.